# I am trying to merge accounts. When It asks to put the stack exchange profile's link

Tags: support, merge-accounts

I gave "network profile" link https://stackexchange.com/users/1552760/basam-nath
but it says that is not correct. where do I get profile link?

Comment: I think they mean the site profiles like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1444773/basam-nath) or [here](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/134601/basam-nath)

Comment: What accounts are you trying to merge? Link to the profiles of both (on any Q&A site).